# Two databases in flask with sqlalchemy, one for reading and one for writing data, is it possible

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask web app where I need two use two existing databases. The first database (DB-A) is used only for reading data (not writing permissions). The second database (DB-B) I am allowed read/write.

I can read DB-A using automap extension

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(db.engine, reflect=True)
DB-A = Base.classes.visitors
```

Reading and writing in DB-B I do ti with sqlalchemy common ORM

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ""   
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

According to the documentation SQLALCHEMY_BINDS should do the work, but I cannt find anything about, how can I tell my automap engine to read a specific database.

my question is, how can I use automap for reading DB-A along with NOT-automap for writing in DB-B?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this part](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/) of the documentation in Flask explaining how to bind multiple databases?

Quote from documentation:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgres://localhost/main'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'users':        'mysqldb://localhost/users',
    'appmeta':      'sqlite:////path/to/appmeta.db'
}
```

And when this is setup, you can use the following (also quote from documentation):

```
>>> db.create_all()
>>> db.create_all(bind=['users'])
>>> db.create_all(bind='appmeta')
>>> db.drop_all(bind=None)
```